# Trying to sort and remove few columns before email it as an attachment using App Scripts but shows errors?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am sending a Google sheet Tab to students and it is working fine. But before sending it to them, I need to sort the sheet using Column3 value and then remove column2, column4, column5, column7. But it shows errors:

> "TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or
> undefined" at contents.sort() and contents.delete() in the codes
> below.

I reviewed many posts but can't figure out the issue.

```
Function sendEmails(){
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssID = sss.getId();
  var sheetName = sss.getName(); 
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = sh.getSheetByName("TempDataSet");
  var shID = sheet1.getSheetId().toString();
 
  var subject = 'Your Attendance Record at BDU';
  var body = 'Dear Student,'+ '\n\n' + 'Greetings! Please find the attendance record attached for your reference.' + '\n\n' + 'Thank you.';
  
  var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};  
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ssID+"&gid="+shID;

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var contents = result.getContent();
  var column = 3;
  contents.sort({column: column, ascending:true});
  contents.delete({column: column2, column4, column5, column7});
           
  var sheet2 = sh.getSheetByName('StudentList');  
  var data = sheet2.getLastRow();
  var students = [];
  var students = sheet2.getRange(2, 6, data).getValues();  
  
  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++){ // you are looping through rows and selecting the 1st and only column index
    if (students[i][0] !== ''){           
      MailApp.sendEmail(students[i][0].toString(), subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xlsx"}]});     
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: That form of a sort function only works for a range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

My suggestion would be to just create a copy of the `TempDataSet` sheet and do all the **sort** and **delete** columns operations on that sheet:

```
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = sh.getSheetByName("TempDataSet");
  var sheet1 = sheet.copyTo(sh).setName('TempDataSet_temp');
  var shID = sheet1.getSheetId().toString();
  sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() -1, sheet.getLastColumn()).sort({column: 3, ascending: true}); 
  var columns_delete = [7,5,4,2];
  columns_delete.forEach(col=>sheet1.deleteColumn(col));
```

then you can delete the temporary sheet after you saved it in the `result` variable:

```
sh.deleteSheet(sh.getSheetByName('TempDataSet_temp'))
```

---

### Solution:

```
function sendEmails(){
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssID = sss.getId();
  var sheetName = sss.getName(); 
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = sh.getSheetByName("TempDataSet");
  var sheet1 = sh.insertSheet('TempDataSet_temp');
  sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet1.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet1.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
  
  var shID = sheet1.getSheetId().toString();
  sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() -1, sheet.getLastColumn()).sort({column: 3, ascending: true}); 
  var columns_delete = [7,5,4,2];
  columns_delete.forEach(col=>sheet1.deleteColumn(col));
 
  var subject = 'Your Attendance Record at BDU';
  var body = 'Dear Student,'+ '\n\n' + 'Greetings! Please find the attendance record attached for your reference.' + '\n\n' + 'Thank you.';
  
  var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};  
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ssID+"&gid="+shID;

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var contents = result.getContent();
  sh.deleteSheet(sh.getSheetByName('TempDataSet_temp'))
           
  var sheet2 = sh.getSheetByName('StudentList');  
  var data = sheet2.getLastRow();
  var students = [];
  var students = sheet2.getRange(2, 6, data).getValues();  
  
  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++){ // you are looping through rows and selecting the 1st and only column index
    if (students[i][0] !== ''){           
      MailApp.sendEmail(students[i][0].toString(), subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]});     
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221606/discussion-on-answer-by-marios-trying-to-sort-and-remove-few-columns-before-emai).